# How to Change Text Color of tab Layout?

Tags: android, layout, android-tablayout

I have this code for change color of text of tab layout,
but it does not work at all!

`app:tabTextColor` does not work, and it cant change color to white.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/blue"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: your background is white and you want your tabtextcolor to be white

Comment: what do you want explain. can you upload your screenshot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can customize your TabLayout's text.

Create a TextView from Java Code or XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/tabs_default_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Make sure to keep the id as it is here because the TabLayout check for this ID if you use custom TextView

Then from code inflate this layout and set the custom Typeface on that TextView and add this custom view to the tab.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
 TextView tv=(TextView)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,null)
 tv.setTextColor(customColor)
 tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tv);

}
```

Comment: tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tv); 
it adds view in stack, any idea to avoid views stack?

Answer (score 95):

Try with it -

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Comment: Addition: if you want multiple themes to select from, just put <item name="tabTextColor">@color/...</item> into the style that you put on your Tablayout (put the style on the tablayout like this in the layout xml file: style="?attr_tab_style")

Answer (score 12):

Use this code it would help in all api level api 18 to api 26

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager,true);
        tabLayout.setSelected(true);

        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHintTextLight),
                  getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryTextLight));

<color name="colorHintTextLight">#80FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryTextLight">#FFFFFF</color>
```

that would help u.it helps me when tab layout change the position.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/color"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:tabTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/showcase"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TAB 1"
                />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TAB 2" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TAB 3" />
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```